# What do I return from the LinkedInAuthenticationProvider.OnAuthenticated delegate?

Tags: oauth, async-await, linkedin-api, owin, katana

`OnAuthenticated` is a `Func<LinkedInAuthenticationContext, Task>` and is a member of the `LinkedInAuthenticationProvider` class. I do not want to return anything from it. I basically just want to subscribe to this delegate to print a few diagnostic details to the debug window.

How do I return a task that means nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I return a task that means nothing

```
Task.FromResult(true);
```

Or:

```
Task dummy = new Task(()=> {return;});
dummy.Start();

return dummy;
```

EDIT:

You can define a static class for that matter:

```
public static class CompletedTask
{
    private static readonly Task _completed = new Task(()=> {return;});
    static CompletedTask()
    {
        _completed.Start();
    }

    public static Task GetCompletedTask()
    {
        return _completed;
    }       
}
```

They did the same thing in project Orleans - `TaskDone` class.

Comment: Thank you. Is the second snippet in your answer the best way to return a task that doesn't have a generic type parameter? In other words a task that represents an operation that doesn't return anything or returns `void`?

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you. :-)